# How to order by month starting from October?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to bring the month into columns like in pivot. But first I would like to order by the month. How can I order the month starting from October as the first month?

October | November | December | January |  ....

```
CREATE TABLE #month
(
 [ID] INT,
 [Date] DATETIME
)
GO
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (1,'2013-04-04')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (2,'2013-07-07')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (3,'2013-10-10')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (4,'2013-01-01')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (5,'2013-02-02')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (6,'2013-03-03')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (7,'2013-05-05')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (8,'2013-06-06')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (9,'2013-08-08')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (10,'2013-09-09')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (11,'2013-11-11')
INSERT INTO #month VALUES (12,'2013-12-12')
GO

SELECT
  DATENAME(month,Date) AS [Month Name]
, [Date]
FROM #month
group by DATENAME(month,Date) 
, [Date]
ORDER BY min([Date])
```

Comment: If the Order by October, December, January, where does November fit in? Will all the dates be for the same year (as per your example)? If not, what order would the dates be in? October 13, October 14, December 13, December 14... November 14?

Comment: Sorry, October | November | December | January |

Comment: Yes is for 12 month period but start from October till September.

Comment: If this were a fiscal year scenario then wouldn't your Oct to Dec data be for 2012? In that case you'd still just order by the actual dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another option

```
SELECT
  DATENAME(month,Date) AS [Month Name]
, [Date]
FROM #month
group by DATENAME(month,Date) 
, [Date]
ORDER BY choose(datepart(month,date),4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one method, whereby you take 10 away from the month number, and add 10 to the months that end up with a result less than 0:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM #month
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]) - 10 < 0 THEN DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]) + 10
                                                   ELSE DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]) - 10
         END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional sorting with a `CASE` expression in the ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY MONTH(min([Date])) + 
         CASE WHEN MONTH(min([Date])) < 10 THEN 12 ELSE 0 END
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a694d97a7fcff7b3f2f981bbdbceb2ad).
Results:

```
> Month Name | Date      
> :--------- | :---------
> October    | 2013-10-10
> November   | 2013-11-11
> December   | 2013-12-12
> January    | 2013-01-01
> February   | 2013-02-02
> March      | 2013-03-03
> April      | 2013-04-04
> May        | 2013-05-05
> June       | 2013-06-06
> July       | 2013-07-07
> August     | 2013-08-08
> September  | 2013-09-09
```

Answer (score 0):

You really just need to add three months to compensate as starting in October could be logically treated as "Month -3". Adding back three brings your sequence into alignment with the regular ordering.

```
order by month(dateadd(month, 3, <date expression>))
```

Comment: Considering the OP has no aggregation in their query, the `GROUP BY` clause is completely redundant in their query, and `MIN("date")` might as well be `date`.

Comment: You're probably right, I just kinda glanced at it and put that in instead of a placeholder date.

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, Date) AS [Month Name], Date
FROM #month
ORDER BY DATEPART(MONTH, Date) + ((1 - (DATEPART(MONTH, Date) / 10)) * 12)
```